# Initializing a class variable with array of class functions

Tags: python, class-variables, first-class-functions

I would like to create an array of member functions as a class variable so I can switch throughout the class etc. The following doesn't work

```
class A:
    def b(self):
        pass

    def c(self):
        pass

    d = [A.b, A.c]
```

because A is not yet created. Is there a workaround for that? I've managed to think of two: 1) initialize the class variable in `__init__` which I don't like because it will cause it to be reinitialized with every object created; and 2) create it as global variable which I also don't like since it's only used within the class and so should be a class variable.

Comment: Hi there, can you include how you're planning on using the array (list) to _switch throughout the class_?

Comment: Assuming I have `d` as above, I can have integer `i` describe a state, so `b` and `c` would implement an abstract operation for states 0 and 1 respectively and then I can call `d[i](self)`.

Comment: Ok, cool. Your workaround #1 seems like the most feasible. I don't see what's wrong with having to initialise different `.b()` and `.c()` functions (or reinitialise the `d`). Are your `.b()` and `.c()` common throughout the entire class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `A.b` there since, as you say, `A` isn't done being defined yet. But you can pick up the functions by their name from the namespace directly:

```
class A:
    def b(self):
        pass

    def c(self):
        pass

    d = [b, c]
```

However, this does not help you, because now you have a list of *unbound* methods:

```
>>> A().d[0]()
TypeError: b() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

If you want a list of *bound* methods (where `self` is implicitly passed as the current instance), you'll need to create that list when you have an actual instance:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = [self.b, self.c]

    ...
```

Alternatively you'll need to pass `self` explicitly to the unbound method:

```
class A:
    ...

    d = [b, c]

    def foo(self):
        self.d[0](self)
```

Comment: It.. didn't occur to me I can omit the class name within the namespace. That solved the problem.